# Should I instantiate Hypothesis strategies that are used by multiple tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, hypothesis-test

The built-in hypothesis strategies are provided via functions (e.g. rather than an actual strategy, `integers` is a function that creates a strategy). That suggests to me that strategy objects have internal state.

```
@given(integers())
def test_foo(n):
    assert n > 0    
@given(integers())
def test_bar(n):
    assert n < 100
```

In the two bogus tests above, each test gets a different strategy object (from different invocations of `integers`. If I then create my own strategy like this:

```
positive_integers = integers().filter(lambda x: x > 0)
```

... then use it for the same tests:

```
@given(positive_integers)
def test_foo(n):
    assert n > 0    
@given(positive_integers)
def test_bar(n):
    assert n < 100
```

They share the same strategy object. This sounds to me like it might be wrong, but it's the way the [examples in the docs](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html) do it in some cases (see definition of `NodeStrategy` and `NodeSet`). Should I avoid this by wrapping the strategy composition in a function like:

```
 positive_integers = lambda: integers().filter(lambda x: x > 0)
 #...
 @given(positive_integers())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at the [source code](https://github.com/HypothesisWorks/hypothesis-python/blob/3.6.0/src/hypothesis/strategies.py#L190), and it looks like you should be fine to share the same strategy object across tests. It seems like you call a function so you can pass in different parameters for the strategy.

I think that means you could do either this:

```
@given(integers(min_value=0))
def test_foo(n):
    assert n > 0    
@given(integers(min_value=0))
def test_bar(n):
    assert n < 100
```

or this:

```
positive_integers = integers(min_value=0)

@given(positive_integers)
def test_foo(n):
    assert n > 0    
@given(positive_integers)
def test_bar(n):
    assert n < 100
```

I couldn't see any evidence of state beyond the range boundaries. In fact, the [`BoundedIntStrategy`](https://github.com/HypothesisWorks/hypothesis-python/blob/3.6.0/src/hypothesis/searchstrategy/numbers.py#L90) seems to get the search data passed in as a parameter:

```
def do_draw(self, data):
    return d.integer_range(data, self.start, self.end)
```

However, I've only played a little bit with Hypothesis, so I could certainly be wrong.